# What is the best color profile to use for a PNG file for CSS Sprites?

Tags: css, png, photoshop, color-profile

I am using a PNG file as CSS Sprites, and the color profile is making the PNG colors look different on Firefox and on Chrome (on a Macbook Pro)

What is the best color profile to use before saving this PhotoShop file (.psd) as a PNG file?  (or best to remove it completely and how?)

---

Details:

This is the Edit -> Color Settings in PhotoShop CS5:
[image]

What should they be set to before saving the file as PNG? (or can change it when saving?)

Also, it is really strange that on Chrome, if I look at the file at

http://foobar:9000/images/sprites.png

or

http://localhost:3000/images/sprites.png

the color orange looks dark.

but if I view the same image on

http://foobar.mycompany.com:9000/images/sprites.png

or

http://hello.mycompany.com:8080/images/sprites.png   (using ssh tunnel into my localhost)

now the color orange is bright.  They point to the exact same file and even if I download them and do a diff, they are binary equal.  Anybody knows why?

Comment: you realize none of those links work because they're all local to your machine?

Comment: ah right... and those links are "made up"... (haha, isn't it obvious?) hmm... you want to see a sample...?   But it will be hard to make it localhost:3000 for you unless you host a server and use that image...

Answer (score 3):

Update: Photoshop CC allows you to uncheck the "embed color profile" option to not embed a profile.  It's *strongly* recommended that you do this unless you have a really good reason not to.

---

The short answer is, unfortunately, you're screwed with ANY color profile.  Your best bet is to use none, but you can't actually get photoshop to save files like that.  This topic has thousands of discussions and opinions, but deleting the color profile allows browsers to interpret the colors of pngs the same way as HTML Hex colors.

Personally, I strip all my color data using a custom script, but something like TweakPNG should allow you to do the same.

Comment: so you mean TweakPNG can remove the color profile but PhotoShop can't...  you know if PNGOUT, Paint.net, IrfranView, or GIMP, Fireworks... any of those can?

Comment: 'save for web' in photoshop allows you to untick 'embed color profile' - that should do the trick...

Comment: @fideldonson -- Thanks, that option didn't exist before (this question _is_ 4 years old ;))

Comment: @zyklus feels like i have spent my entire life dealing with color profile issues - and i still don't get it - so 4 years is nothing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you should not be using a color profile at all and ensuring "convert to sRGB" is turned off.

See [this article](http://www.viget.com/inspire/the-mysterious-save-for-web-color-shift/) for a better explanation on why and how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your color management policies to Off. I'm not sure if that will help, but it might.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tricky issue, as level of support for color profiles varies between browsers.

Using sRGB gamma 2.2 is a good start.

If you need CSS colors to match PNG colors, then you'll have to remove color profile and gamma information from the PNG, since most browsers don't color-manage CSS colors (or if they do, they process them the same way as unlabelled PNGs).

http://imageoptim.com/color-profiles.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is an answer. Safari and Chrome assume that all images are saved in the sRGB color space.

Safari will take into account a different color profile embedded in the image, but Chrome will not.

Firefox does not take anything into account, and will just use the native RGB values.

This means that colors in Firefox on a wide-color (P3) screen like a Macbook pro will look extremely vivid compared to the sRGB colors displayed in Chrome and Safari.

Alternatively, you can apply the P3 profile to the images and they will display as vivid in Safari and Firefox, but washed-out in Chrome.

There is no one setting that applies to all browsers.